# Create class that uses updated version of an input

Tags: python

I'd like to create a class that can use the current version of the data inputted to it.
I've tried:

```
class DisplayUpdatedNum:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.the_num = number
    def print_num(self):
        print(f'the number is {self.the_num}')


my_num = 1
class_inst = DisplayUpdatedNum(my_num)
class_inst.print_num()
# requested output: the number is 1

my_num = 1905
class_inst.print_num()
# requested output: the number is 1905
```

This doesn't work, I get the original input number (`1`) when calling `class_inst.print_num()` even after changing `my_num`

Is there a pythonic solution to this?

Comment: Whynot make the class print the global argument 'my_num' no need to make it a member of the class, or simply make a getter, so that before the printing you either update the number, or pass it as an argument.

Comment: No. You're passing the _value_, 1, for the instance to keep a reference to, not the _identifier_. Read e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: "Is there a pythonic solution to this?" No, what you are asking for is fundamentally a bad design. The *entire purpose* of a class / OOP is to *encapsulate state*. So yeah, you could use a global variable, you could wrap your `int` in a mutable object and mutate that, both solutions would be bad for the aforementioned reason. The best solution is *not to do this at all*

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, what you are trying to do is a bad design (as already mentioned):

**Attention: (bad solution)**

```
num = 10
class DispalyUpdateNum(object):
    global num

    def print_num(self):
        print(num)


c = DispalyUpdateNum()
c.print_num()

num = 100
c.print_num()

>>>10
>>>100
```

Much better would be if you use the @property, something like this :

```
class DispalyUpdateNum(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value
        print("The number is %s" % self._value)


c = DispalyUpdateNum()
c.value = 100
c.value = 10000
c.value = 777

>>> The number is 100
>>> The number is  10000
>>> The number is  777
```

Would this solution fit in your code is up to you, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The class does not have the responsibility to be aware of the changes of a variable at the global level. In fact one of the principles of OOP is to encapsulate the variables that give context to the class (data attributes). There is no pythonic way, but there a straightforward OOP way:

```
from numbers import Real

class DisplayUpdatedNum:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._the_num = number
    @property
    def num(self):
        return self._the_num
    @num.setter
    def num(self,value):
        if not isinstance(value,Real):
             raise TypeError('Not a valid numeric type!') #you have now the chance to do some validations here (if you need to)
        self._the_num = value 
    def print_num(self):
        print(f'the number is {self._the_num}')
```

Now you can instaciate your custom class, and when you want to change the valua of the `_the_num` pseudo-private attr, you just call the `num` interface that gives you the property class with his getter and setter:

```
my_num = 1
class_inst = DisplayUpdatedNum(my_num)
class_inst.print_num()
# requested output: the number is 1

my_num = 1905
class_inst.num = my_num
class_inst.print_num()
# requested output: the number is 1905

# Try the basic validation
my_mun = '1905'
class_inst.num = my_num
class_inst.print_num()
# requested output: TypeError: Not a valid numeric type!
```

Also if you want a little bit further in OOP and combinate it to pythonic ways to do this kind of thing, you could read up about `data desciptors`